# How to handle a firestore group with more than 40,000 members

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Firestore says that they have a limit of 40,000 index's for all documents in a collection. Currently I am creating a database where users can join and create groups.

The structure that im thinking of is

```
{  
  "name": "Example Group",  
  "users": [  
    "username1",  
    "username2"  
    etc...  
  ]  
  ...  
}
```

as well as have it linked on each user

```
{
  "name": "Username1",
  "Groups": [
    "Example Group1",
    "Example Group2"
    etc...
  ]
  ...
}
```

As you can see I am storing the user list of a group in an array and storing the list of groups joined by a user in an array as well. If a group has over 40,000 users (which some groups may have), will the array break in firestore? How many users could a group possibly have?

Also if the array gets too big, what will happen? When would i have problems with this?

Answer (score 1):

Documents like this will get unwieldy pretty quickly. The solution is to store the groups for a user in a subcollection under that users, and similarly the users for a group in a subcollection under that group.

That removes the need for the ridiculous number of indexes (and associated cost), and allows you to more flexibly query the separate documents in the subcollection.

Comment: Oh i see, it makes sense to store the Users in a group in a subcollection. Just wondering, why store the groups a user is in, in a subcollection as well? Considering a User is unlikely to join more than lets say 20-100 groups